# Add a top level file in jar made with lein jar

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am trying to create an [atlassian's bamboo plugin](https://developer.atlassian.com/bamboodev/bamboo-plugin-guide/bamboo-plugin-module-types/build-lifecycle-plugin-modules/task-plugin-module) in clojure.  The jar must contains a file called `atlassian-plugin.xml` at top level.  How can I do so with leiningen.  I expect to create my jar using `lein jar`.

cheers!

didier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put atlassian-plugin.xml in src (not sub folder) or resource folder. It will be on the top level same as project.clj.